# Why doesn't my javascript dynamic image placement work like my hard-coded version?

Tags: javascript, html

I have successfully created an html/javascript document that overlays a mostly transparent image (t01.png) over an identically-sized background image (map.png) using hard-coded "`<div>`" and "`<img>`" tags.

I want to replicate the results using the javascript createElement command in place of the hard-coded tags, but the page that gets displayed has the second image placed lower down the page from the background image, rather than overlaying it as desired.

What do I need to change to make the dynamic image placement work the same as the hard-coded version?

**Hard-coded version:**

```
<html>
<head>

<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var iImage = 0;
var imageFiles = ["./map.png","./t01.png"]
var numImages = 2;

function imageLoad() {
  for(iImage = 0; iImage < numImages; iImage++) {
    document.images[iImage].src = imageFiles[iImage];
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="imageLoad();">
    <div id="imageBox" STYLE="position: absolute; top:0px; height: 1px;">
      <div ID="frame0" STYLE="position: absolute; top: 0em; left: 0em;">
        <img src="./map.png" border="1">
      </div>
      <div ID="frame1" STYLE="position: absolute;top: 0em; left: 0em;">
        <img src="./t01.png" border="1">
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Dynamic-placement version**

```
<html>
<head>

<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var iImage = 0;
var imageFiles = ["./map.png","./t01.png"]
var numImages = 2;

function imageLoad() {
  placeImage();
  for(iImage = 0; iImage < numImages; iImage++) {
    document.images[iImage].src = imageFiles[iImage];
  }
}

function placeImage()
{
  for(iImage = 0; iImage < numImages; iImage++) {

    // Create div for this image.
    var thisDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var thisDivID = "frame" + iImage;
    thisDiv.id = thisDivID;
    thisDiv.position = "absolute";

    // Create image.
    var thisImage = document.createElement("img");
    thisImage.src=imageFiles[iImage];

    // Add this image to this div.
    thisDiv.appendChild(thisImage);

    // Add this div to the imageBox div.
    document.getElementById("imageBox").appendChild(thisDiv);

  }
}

</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="imageLoad();">
    <div id="imageBox" STYLE="position: absolute; top:0px; height: 1px;"></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Background layer--map.png]
[image: Mostly transparent layer--t01.png]

Comment: The hard-coded version appears to set 'top' and 'left' of 'frame0' and 'frame1' to '0em'. I don't see that happening to 'thisDiv' in the dynamic version.

Comment: Good catch, but adding those attributes to the dynamic version doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Did you use 'thisDiv.style.[position/top/left]'? I intended to comment on the provided answer that you had already inlined the imageBox, but if you wanted to do it in code, it would only need done once.

Comment: Yes, I used `thisDiv.style.top = "0em";` and `thisDiv.style.left = "0em";`

Comment: I usually move inline style definitions to class definitions in a style section, then set the class of newly created items to that. I was more familiar with the el.setAttribute( ) functionality so I didn't answer immediately in case I got the syntax wrong for specific style elements. I wanted to stay close to your implemented strategy. Glad Nikunj's answer worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not giving any style to elements in your dynamic-placement version that is the issue here

try this in your code

```
thisDiv.style.position="absolute";
thisDiv.style.top="0em";
thisDiv.style.left="0em";

document.getElementById("imageBox").style.top="0px";
document.getElementById("imageBox").style.height="1px";
document.getElementById("imageBox").style.position="absolute";
```

and give style like this to other required elements also for which you have given style in your static hard coded version.

Comment: That fixed it, though the only one of the six lines you suggested that actually needed to be changed was `thisDiv.style.position="absolute";` I was doing `thisDiv.position="absolute";', which I thought was the same thing. (the imageBox style settings were handled in the body html). Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin OK, glad it helped you.